# apache spark: Completed application history deleted after restarting

Tags: apache-spark, spark-webui

When I restart spark cluster all of history of completed application in web ui are deleted. How can I preserve this history from deleting when restarting?

Answer (score 1):

Spark itself doesn't store logs. If you want to store them then you need to enable that config by using "`spark.eventLog`":

```
./bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
--master spark://10.129.6.11:7077 \
--conf spark.eventLog.enabled=true \
--conf spark.eventLog.dir="hdfs://your path" \
/home/spark/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.2.1.jar 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't restart spark master. Just make it got query like Zeppelin.

Comment: Suppose the server crashes or turns off... . what should I do now?

Comment: @DAVID_ROA Usually spark history log is stored on HDFS. Can you find that?

Comment: No, I think I should enable a property or set a config, but I don't know what it is.